# System.Text.Json converts to Single instead of float

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have json that I need to convert to "19.99" let's say number to float or any other that handles the value.
Here's my json:

```
 "book": {
      "Id": "12345",
      "externalBookId": "67890",
      "name": "Sample Book",
      "description": "This is a sample book",
      "cost": 19.99, // this value convert to Single instead of float
      "externalClientId": "ABC123"
  }
```

this is C# model:

```
public class Book {
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? ExternalBookId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public float Cost { get; set; }
    public string? ExternalClientId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
 var jsonObject = JsonDocument.Parse(json)
            .RootElement.GetProperty(typeof(TEntity).Name.ToLower());
foreach (var property in jsonObject.EnumerateObject()) {
}
```

How can I set it to work with specific type: float, int, or anything else?

Comment: Use Newtonsoft.Json instead of Text.Json

Comment: Why don't you parse into the Book model directly? Datatype should then be handled correctly.

Comment: A better option is to deserialize to `Book`, thus telling STJ what to use. `var book=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Book>(json);`

Comment: Is there a difference between Single and float? I thought they are the same and double is, well ... double.

Comment: That value shouldn't be a floating point type anyway.

Comment: Agree with @Fildor-standswithMods. You book will likely cost 19,98999999998321 € in the end due to IEEE754 issues. Use `decimal`.

Comment: Cost should be decimal, not float, 'cause MS recommended decimal for currency operations

Comment: As has been mentioned here before me, you should use a different data type for currency; either store the variables as cents/pennies/whatever (`int`) and then divide by 100, or store the values as a `decimal`.

Comment: You should be using double because it's closer to the JSON spec which has one number type which is related to JavaScript's number. Also `float` is just a language specific alias for `System.Single`

Comment: @Ralf it didn't but after that I need to run a custom validation on that. Is there a library that can load from db a set of validations and run on the entity it self?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question for a completely different audience.